# how do antd forms work with react?

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

From my understanding of react, it keeps state of where the form is and this state is used to re-render the form whenever the state finds itself changed.  Whenever the user changes the form input the onchange notification will first modify the state.  So far so good.

I am trying to understand how antd changes this flow of state control when it is used alongside react.  The documentation on antd is cryptic and the philosophy behind its state changes is insufficiently explained.

So what we have is that antd has a fieldDecorator which effectively turns the field into a react/antd controlled component. My question is that once the control is changed in antd where it is keeping the state?  Because multiple react components might be involved and how does one find out which component holds the state.

I am trying to fit in a multiple step form over multiple pages, and without understanding how antd is doing it it is difficult to design this multi step component.   Would be great for the antd folks to respond on how exactly it interacts with the react mechanism and how those are displaced by getFieldDecorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is stored local to the Form component. You cannot get at the internal state storage. To build a multiple component wizard you need to extract state to your own storage (via the `onFieldsChange` prop). If you need the wizard to persist state when the user gows back/forward you use a combo of `onFieldsChange` and `mapPropsToFields`.

Here is a snippet from one of my forms that does something similar using `store`:

```
class MyForm extends Component {
...
}

export default Form.create( {
    onFieldsChange: ( props, fields ) => {
        props.onChange( fields ) // Set on parent!
        let previousData = store.get( 'MyForm' ) || {}
        _forEach( fields, field => {
            previousData[ field.name ] = field.value
        } )
        store.set( 'MyForm', previousData )
    },

    mapPropsToFields: ( props ) => {
        let fields = {}
        _forEach( props.myForm /* Get from parent! */, ( info, field ) => {
            fields[ field ] = Form.createFormField( info )
        } )
        return fields
    }
} )(
        translate( [ 'common' ], { wait: true } )(MyForm)
)
```